# PyCharm not detecting Python 2.7 on my Mint 19

Tags: python, pycharm, linux-mint

I'm trying to use PyCharm with Python 2.7 in Mint 19, but only versions 3 and 3.7 are detected. Before, I had to install manually Python 2.7. I though I had something wrong during the installation, but in terminal it works (see screenshot below). Any idea why this would happen? Thanks a lot!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please note that python 2.7 is not supported anymore since 01/01/2020, avoid it if you can.

Comment: Have you tried restarting PyCharm after installing Python 2.7? Maybe it hasn't updated the list somehow

Comment: Are there more options in the interpreter field in `System Interpreter` tab?

Comment: I restarted the software, but not the hole PC. I'm out now, let's see if after my return, switching it again, it works. And thanks for the advice on moving to Python 3. I'm not a real programmer, I just do some scripting from time to time, and I needed to check some code I wrote on 2.7, 2 years ago. Thanks!